# Best practices: Custom theme sidebar menu - hardcode or widget?

Tags: theme-development, menus, sidebar, customization, register-sidebar

Is it best to hardcode a sidebar menu using functions.php or sidebar.php OR use the custom menu widget?  Are there times when each is appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some degree, the answer depends on the *intended use* of the sidebar menu, but in general, it is best to allow the greatest degree of freedom to the end user.

If the *intended use* of the sidebar menu is to be, well, a *navigation menu*, then I would strongly recommend supporting the core Nav Menus feature. If the intended use of the navigation menu exceeds to functionality of the core feature, then you can always define a custom callback that will implement your advanced functionality.

I use this approach with my Oenology Theme. I have a sidebar menu that dynamically displays sub-menus of static Pages. One limitation of the core Nav Menu feature is that it is not dynamic. Every time the user adds a static Page, the user has to update the existing custom menu manually.

But, the way I implemented it was to define a `theme_location` for my sidebar menu, but defined my callback using `wp_list_pages()`, with custom arguments. That way, the default/fallback behavior is a *dynamic* menu, but the end user has the option to *override* the default behavior, if needing/wanting a custom menu.

Comment: Found this post as a great way to preset widget areas. http://themeshaper.com/2009/07/06/wordpress-theme-sidebar-template/